# Filter SQL query on the generated results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a plpgsql function that generates TSTZRANGEs between two dates according to stored rules in a table called `timeslots`. It is working fine but now I got a new requirement and added a TSTZRANGE field called `datespan` to the `timeslots` table that I also need to filter against, so that only ranges contained within this field's value are returned.

Showing you here part of the function I need to change. `eid`, `fromdate` and `todate` are parameters passed in to the function.

```
SELECT TSTZRANGE(
    (series::DATE + ts1.start)::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
    (series::DATE + ts1.end)::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
) AS range
FROM
  timeslots AS ts1,
  generate_series(fromdate, todate, '1 day') AS series
WHERE
  eid = ts1.event_id AND
  EXTRACT(DOW FROM series) = ANY(ts1.weekdays)
ORDER BY
  range
```

So what I want to do is add a filter like `WHERE range <@ ts1.datespan` but I can't manage to put it anywhere that works.

EXAMPLE:
Given this information in `timeslots` table:

```
 id |  start   |   end    |   weekdays    | event_id |           datespan 
----+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 12:00:00 | 14:00:00 | {1,2,3,5,6,0} |       1  | ["2017-01-01 00:00:00+00","2017-02-01 00:00:00+00")
 2  | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 | {1,2,3,5,6,0} |       1  | [null, null)
 3  | 15:00:00 | 17:00:00 | {1,2,3,5,6,0} |       1  | ["2017-02-01 00:00:00+00","2017-03-01 00:00:00+00")
```

The result of calling the SELECT above if `eid=1`, `fromdate='2017-02-02'` and `todate='2017-02-03'` should look like this:

```
                        range                        
-----------------------------------------------------
 ["2017-02-02 09:00:00+00","2017-02-02 11:00:00+00")
 ["2017-02-02 15:00:00+00","2017-02-02 17:00:00+00")
 ["2017-02-03 09:00:00+00","2017-02-03 11:00:00+00")
 ["2017-02-03 15:00:00+00","2017-02-03 17:00:00+00")
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to use `lateral`:

> The LATERAL key word can precede a sub-SELECT FROM item. This allows the sub-SELECT to refer to columns of FROM items that appear before it in the FROM list. (Without LATERAL, each sub-SELECT is evaluated independently and so cannot cross-reference any other FROM item.)

```
select ts1.*, range
from
    timeslots as ts1,
    generate_series('2017-02-02'::date, '2017-02-03', '1 day') as series
    cross join lateral
    (
        select tstzrange (
            (series::date + ts1.start)::timestamptz at time zone 'utc',
            (series::date + ts1.end)::timestamptz at time zone 'utc'
        ) as range
    ) range
where
    1 = ts1.event_id and
    extract(dow from series) = any(ts1.weekdays) and
    range <@ ts1.datespan
order by range
;
 id |  start   |   end    |   weekdays    | event_id |                      datespan                       |                        range                        
----+----------+----------+---------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
  2 | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 | {1,2,3,5,6,0} |        1 | (,)                                                 | ["2017-02-03 09:00:00+00","2017-02-03 11:00:00+00")
  3 | 15:00:00 | 17:00:00 | {1,2,3,5,6,0} |        1 | ["2017-02-01 00:00:00+00","2017-03-01 00:00:00+00") | ["2017-02-03 15:00:00+00","2017-02-03 17:00:00+00")
```

The alternative would be to wrap it in an outer query. Now you need to decide/inform what to do with the null boundaries.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Empty values in ranges means that it is unbounded so the range `[null, null)` will contain all other ranges, but maybe that's not the correct notation.